# What is a NULL in hexadecimal

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I have to debug a C application in assembler. I want to know if a register is containing a 
`NULL` . I need for that the hex value of that.

Note:

I use a PPC

Comment: Ehm... why do you think you need the hex version of the value?

Comment: `NULL` is zero, zero is `NULL`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Null is `00` in hexadecimal.

Kindly refer to this: 
http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Don't you mean 00h?  ;-)  ;-)

Comment: No, he meant 0x00 ;-)

Comment: @Blake: http://www.asciitable.com/ or the OP's original link have nothing to do with this; the question is about NULL, not NUL.  But yes, I think all PowerPC compilers use `0` as the object-representation for NULL pointers.  The C standard doesn't require that, though, and apparently there is/was at least one real-world C implementation that used a non-zero bit-pattern for `(void*)0` aka `NULL`.